# Read a file with numerical values

Tags: python

I have a file that has numerical values in two columns like

```
00000000, 1625151029.99
00000001, 1625151030.03
 .....
```

etc.
What is a simple way to read these values into an array or a dictionary in python, without using for example Panda.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `.txt` file, you can do this:

```
filename='.... .txt'
with open(filename,'r') as file:
    r=file.readlines()
    dict1={k:v for k in r.strip("\n").split(",")}
```

Comment: mm I tried it, but it says "list" object as no attribute 'strip'